# Can't display replies for @post.replies

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this happens at the `User` show page where I show posts for certain user The problem is that `@replies.each` ... executes right but does not show replies for post.id I don't know why ... sometimes when I browse other posts i find replies which are not supposed to be there so I think the error is in

`@post = Post.find(params[:id])` but I don't know what to do .

Users controller

```
def posting
     @posts = User.find(params[:id]).posts
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @replies = @post.replies
end
```

thread.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |x| %>
<%= x.content %>
<%= render 'replies' %>
<% end %>
```

_replies.html.erb

```
<% @replies.each do |x| %>
<%= x.content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing two different ideas. The controller code you shared is loading all posts and a single post and the replies for that post. Your question states that you'd like to show all replies for a specific reply. Your view code ls looping over all of the posts but only ever showing the replies loaded from a specific post.

Comment: no sir each post has it's own replies I want to display each group of replies with their respective post that's it

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is you want to get the replies of the specific post, it should be like this:

You controller:

```
@posts = Post.all
```

thread.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |x| %>
  <%= x.content %>
  <%= render 'replies', locals: {replies: x.replies} %>
<% end %>
```

_replies.html.erb

```
<% replies.each do |x| %>
  <%= x.content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I want to call the replies via @post.replies because later i will paginate them and add some ajax functionality so x.replies won't work in this situation or I would have implemented it earliers as it is simple and direct ..

Comment: This answer will let you load all posts, then load each post's replies. Introducing pagination and/or ajax will still be possible. If you move the replies partial in to `app/views/replies/_reply.html.erb` you can probably get away with `render @replies` in your post view. This will probably make ajaxification even easier in the future...

Comment: will i don't see how can i paginate the `x.replies` in your context of an answer as I can't do `<%= paginate x.replies %>` thats why my question had `@replies = @post.replies `